# Allow Radiobuttonsto respond only once usingTkinter()

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I´ve created two Radiobuttons labeled by "Yes" and "No" in one Tab. If "Yes" is selected a new Tab is created. If "No" is selected the created Tab is deleted.

It works fine but the problem is, that the Radiobuttons are responding each time if I click on them, although they are already selected. So for example I can click on "Yes" several times and a new Tab is created respectively. But I want to create a new Tab just once. How can I avoid this?
Or is there another way to create and delete a new Tab dynamically?

Here is my code for creating the Radiobuttons in a Tab (implemented in a class):

```
self.checkVar = tk.BooleanVar(self.tab)
        self.checkY = tk.Radiobutton(self.tab,text="Yes",var=self.checkVar,value=True,comm=self.main.addTab)
        self.checkVar.set(0)
        self.checkY.grid(row=0,sticky="W")
        
        self.checkN = tk.Radiobutton(self.tab,text="No",var=self.checkVar,value=False,comm=self.main.addTab)
        self.checkN.grid(row=1,sticky="W")
```

Here is the code for creating respectively deleting the tabs:

```
def addTab():
#create new Tab
  if self.tab.checkVar.get() == True:
     self.tab_new = Tab_new(self.notebook)
# delete this tab again
  if self.tab.checkVar.get() == False:
     self.notebook.forget(2)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: inside the function try some way to disable the widget. Try something inside the function like `checkY['state'] = tk.DISABLED`

Comment: You can create the tab once and hide it initially.  Then use `add(...)` to show it back and `hide(2)` to hide it inside `addTab()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you make an example? I guess I didn´t get your point. I used `add(...)` in my `class Tab_new` .

Comment: @acw1668 I tried your solution, but again I can press the Radiobutton several times and I have therfore several Tabs, but I want to prevent this.

Comment: An [example](https://pastebin.com/VDhGteue) for your reference.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you very much! It works now. The trick for me was also to write`self.tab_new = Tab_new(self.notebook)` outside of the function. Create the tab and hide it if u don´t need it, otherwise use `add` like u said.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it has to be a more proper way, but this should work I think.

```
x=0
def addTab():
     
    #create new Tab
      if self.tab.checkVar.get() == True and x == 0:
         self.tab_new = Tab_new(self.notebook)
         x = x+1
    
    # delete this tab again
      if self.tab.checkVar.get() == False:
         self.notebook.forget(2)
         x=0
```

Comment: Need to add `global x` at the beginning of `addTab()`.

Comment: @fernando it works, but I have a lot of radiobuttons and therefore I would need a more elegant solution, but thank you :)

Comment: Maybe using deselect()? i don't know if it'd work for you; the radiobutton won't be clicked anymore so It sends a message to the user that if you select it again, you should expect to create another tab.